# Restart apache when content is changed

Tags: apache

When is it necessary to restart apache if content is changed.  We create new directories with new code but all we do is change the symbolic link to the appropriate folder when a new build is added in a new directory.  Do we need to restart apache for this? Can it cause any cache issues?

Comment: `reload` is sufficient. "Can it cause any cache issues?" --- what cache?

Comment: If I'm using mod cache.  And content files are updated.  Can that cause stale cache to be displayed.